# Fix div in place, but allow it to be covered

Tags: html, css

I have some code as follows:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Lorem <small class="text-muted">ipsum dolor sit amet.</small></h1>
        <p>
            Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. 
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Donec</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Aenean</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The header has a fixed background image, and fills the entire page as a cover.

```
.header {
    background: #000 url(/img/cover.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 60px 0 60px 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

When you scroll, the following `<div>` moves up over it, as if it's covering it, however all the text moves as you scroll. I want the text to stay fixed, like the background. I've tried setting `position: fixed;` to `container`, however the text appears on top of the following `div`, and it moves to the side ignoring the `container` margin. How can I do this?

Comment: Try to use `z-index` to tell which block should be on top

Comment: @Justcode Quick example, missing some of the CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/Matrp/ As you can see, the text covers the background image as you scroll, however the text origionally over the bg moves, rather than stays fixed.

Comment: @BenedictLewis a quick example how you can achieve this http://jsfiddle.net/Matrp/2/

Comment: @Justcode Now the text below covers the background image straight away. I want it to stay hidden till you scroll, and it should scroll over the background image and text in the container.

Comment: @BenedictLewis you will have to apply padding for this

Comment: @BenedictLewis like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Matrp/5/

Comment: @Justcode Nope. This is an example of a site which does something similar: http://rodrigob.com/themes/scrn/

Comment: Note that Chrome 29 and less got a bug on background-size: cover + background-attachment: fixed, that makes the background transparent.

Comment: oh @BenedictLewis you should inspect and check that site's css

Answer (score 0):

Add these three lines to CSS .header

```
position: fixed;
z-index: -1;
top: 0;
```

And this to set style for the text container:

```
.ContentText {
   margin-top: 100%; /* I added class="ContentText" to the div with the long text */
}
```

Should work now:

http://jsfiddle.net/Matrp/6/

Update: Last try in response to comment below. Look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Matrp/9/

This time you create a div with class="space" which is just there to provide the needed, well, space.

Comment: Sorry, not what I need. The content text has a background color as well, so I can't use a padding because it will cover up the first text. I want something like [this](http://rodrigob.com/themes/scrn/), where the content div moves over the first one.

Comment: See updated version. You have to use margin instead of padding then.

Comment: I'm not really comfortable doing that, it's very 'hacky'. If you have a look at the link I posted, they don't use a 100% margin or padding to do it.

Comment: If you have a model, why don't you just copy the css rules and replace with your own background and colors ?

Comment: Sorry, don't know what's hacky about that. It does exactly what you asked for. But one last try: I give you another way of doing it in the update.

Comment: @Puzzled I found a solution which didn't require an extra div or other previous answers. z-index the two divs, one with fixed and the other with relative positioning.

Comment: Ok, I see. That's a better solution. Thanks for telling me.